# Where in my Google Map code do I add the code for the map style?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following custom Google Map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 700px;
        height: 700px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.2048114,8.0734625),
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

Using the official guide, I can't figure out where I'm supposed to add the following code:

```
map.set('styles', [
  {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#000000' },
      { weight: 1.6 }
    ]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -100 },
      { invert_lightness: true }
    ]
  }, {
    featureType: 'landscape',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { hue: '#ffff00' },
      { gamma: 1.4 },
      { saturation: 82 },
      { lightness: 96 }
    ]
  }, {
    featureType: 'poi.school',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { hue: '#fff700' },
      { lightness: -15 },
      { saturation: 99 }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: @LuckyChingi Should I have a separate JavaScript file that I'm linking to and if so, will the code as is be sufficient or do I need to enclose it in something similar to jQuery's documents ready function?

Comment: @ClarusDignus I left an answer for you below, you just add the styles in your map options object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add it in the map options:

```
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.2048114,8.0734625),
  zoom: 6,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  styles: [
  {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#000000' },
      { weight: 1.6 }
    ]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -100 },
      { invert_lightness: true }
    ]
  }, {
    featureType: 'landscape',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { hue: '#ffff00' },
      { gamma: 1.4 },
      { saturation: 82 },
      { lightness: 96 }
    ]
  }, {
    featureType: 'poi.school',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { hue: '#fff700' },
      { lightness: -15 },
      { saturation: 99 }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other option (other than putting it in the mapOptions in the google.maps.Map constructor) is to put the code inside the `initialize` function, after the `map` variable is defined:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/evu3gvrs/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.2048114, 8.0734625),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  map.set('styles', [{
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#000000'
    }, {
      weight: 1.6
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
      saturation: -100
    }, {
      invert_lightness: true
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'landscape',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      hue: '#ffff00'
    }, {
      gamma: 1.4
    }, {
      saturation: 82
    }, {
      lightness: 96
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'poi.school',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      hue: '#fff700'
    }, {
      lightness: -15
    }, {
      saturation: 99
    }]
  }]);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I now see, from your answer, that I needed a variable defined to allow me to apply set(). Thanks.for the alternative. Is one approach superior to the other in any way?